# How can I clear the IntelliJ publish cache when I run/debug an AS3 project?

Tags: actionscript-3, caching, intellij-idea

I've setup a secondary project module to symlink from the source folder to a shared resources folder.  This shared resource folder is where I store all of the content for several components.

I realize there is a built-in 'include folder' functionality that would make sense, but the linkages behave differently - specifically, they don't work.

The symbolic link solution works as I'd hoped it to, except that changes made to the resources folder aren't reflected when I recompile the secondary module (caching, I'm sure).  I can resolve this by running the Rebuild Project command ahead of every compile.  It would be nice to automate this step in to my compile configuration.

I've taken a look at the Run/Debug configurations menu, specifically the Before Launch menu.  I wasn't able to figure out a way to do what I needed.

Any ideas?  Also open to alternative solutions to clear publishing caches if you have something else in mind.

Comment: Have you considered running a build script? I'm using Ant in a project similar to yours.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if some sort of build script is required for this.  My Ant knowledge is pretty limited, so my hope was that there was a simple IntelliJ step I was oblivious to.  If you happen to have an Ant script handy to trigger Rebuild Project, I'd happily set about trying to integrate it :)

Comment: I'm afraid there's no handy script. If you have check both `make` and `Run Ant target`, `make` has precedence. So you can't have simple script to let's say delete built files and force recompilation. Actually I don't use `make` at all and the compilation is run from Ant.